# How can i create multiple django project on pycharm without one conflicting with other port

Tags: python, django

I create a django project called Polls and i have one project called registration but anytime i run my polls server it always go to the registration server and display things there also my migrations doesnt go to the polls server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the server, The default port is 8000(127.0.0.1:8000)
if you want to run multiple django projects try using different ports.
For example:
1.) python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8004
2.) python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8008

and etc...